# Dynamically check value and display alarm popover

Tags: javascript, django, validation

I want to validate user input so he only provides numbers from a certain range with 0,5 steps. But I want my website to do it every time user swaps to another input form, not after he sends the data to my view. Can you give a hint of how should it be done? I don't know Javascript but I know there is `onfocusout` DOM event. Is it correct approach to use it, check whether or not value is valid and display an alarm based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there's no problem using `onfocusevent`.

Here's a hint on how to do this:

- Create the input field
- Add the `onfocusout` event handler and assign it a JavaScript function
- Define the JavaScript function responsible for the validation process (which is, the same function we talked about in step 2)
- This function takes the value inside the field and compares it, if it's not inside the range you desire then you can show an alarm or something like this.

I made a demo that doesn't involve alarming the user but instead it colors the border with either green or red, when you get desperate pay it a visit:

```html
<input type="number" id="field1" onfocusout="validateField(0, 100, 'field1')"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="number" id="field2" onfocusout="validateField(200, 300, 'field2')"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="number" id="field3" onfocusout="validateField(400, 500, 'field3')"/><br/><br/>
    <script>
        function validateField(min, max, id) {
            const value = document.getElementById(id).value;
            if (value < min || value > max) {
                document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = "red";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = "lime";
            }
        }
    </script>
```